# Set credentials for Nintex in powershell script for migration to O365

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, migration, office365, nintex-workflow

I am creating a powershell script for migration of a site collection from on-premise to O365. I need to set/configure credentials that will be used for migrating the Nintex WF actions.

In the Sharegate desktop tool, this can be configured through the **Nintex External Providers Configuration**

[image: Nintex External Providers Configuration]

How can I set this in my powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a 3rdParty tool not native PowerShell features to do this migration.
If that tool does provide a cmdlet or switch or API to do this, then you have to code for it.

If this is just a web portal, then you can use the normal browser interaction code to send input to the page.

1. Scrape the page to get the page fields.

   $w = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'SomeUrl'
   $w.Forms
   $w.Forms.Fields
2. Use those fields to post information to the page.

   $ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
   $ie.visible=$true
   $ie.navigate("Url")

   while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}

   $ie.document.getElementById("username").value= "$username" 
   $ie.document.getElementById("pass").value = "$password" 
   $ie.document.getElementById("loginform").submit()